# Airflow does not pick up symlinked DAGs

Tags: airflow, symlink

I want to link in some DAGs from a directory outside of my `dags_folder`. How ever when I create a symlink using

```
ln -s /absolute/path/to/dag.py dags/
```

It does not show up when running `airflow dags list`.
Neither does it show up after hard linking it.

```
ln /absolute/path/to/dag.py dags/
```

If I copy it in though, it shows up almost straight away.

```
cp /absolute/path/to/dag.py dags/
```

Airflow version 2.0.0, provided by the [Astro CLI](https://github.com/astronomer/astro-cli).

Answer (score 0):

if symlink worked before, maybe worked accidentally but it is not the way DAG importing common code should work. All the code that you use should be in the DAGs folder and symbolic links from outside of the DAG folder are not going to work.